# FromDigits Question

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation

Why does the input `FromDigits[Range[10]]` have an output of 1234567900 and not 12345678910?

This seems like a puzzling answer as `FromDigits` is supposed join all the numbers in a list to create one number, so I can't seem to see why it would omit the 8 and make the 10 as a 00

Comment: Because numbers greater than the base are carried.  `FromDigits[2,9]` or  twenty-nine gives 29 but `FromDigits[2,10]` or 'twenty-ten' (to 'count' stupidly) is 30 (and 'twenty-eleven' is 31).

Comment: To those, voting to close as "easily found in the documentation": I've examined the page for `FromDigits`, and the only tangentially related entry there under possible issues is *If no base is specified, the multicharacter strings are converted using base 10: `FromDigits["1A3C"]`* which is shown to be equivalent to `FromDigits[{1,10,3,12}]` with the behavior of the answer below (or tomd's comment). This isn't explicitly stated anywhere, though. Leave open, I say.

Answer (score 5):

Contemplate

```
Fold[#1 10 + #2 &, 0, Range[10]]
```

which performs the same computation as `FromDigits[Range[10]]` Both give

`1234567900`